# the following classes could not be found: com.codecarpet.fbconnect.FBLoginButton

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook, fbconnect

I am trying to connect to Facebook (and eventually Facebook places). I am using the Facebook-android-sdk in Eclipse but I seem to be getting an error message in the graphical view on my `main.xml` class. the error message is:

```
the following classes could not be found: com.codecarpet.fbconnect.FBLoginButton
```

I have imported the `FBLoginButton` as a referenced library but Eclipse still can't manage to locate this class.

There are no errors in my project and all the correct jars and libraries have been imported.

Anyone got any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It might just be a Eclipse problem and not anything with your code. Try going to "Project" menu -> "Clean" on eclipse which might help in this case. Good luck :)